# Can NIST statistic tests suite output random data into a file?

Tags: random

I am able to compile and run the suite. However, is there a way to generate the RNG data into a file?

Appreciate any help.

For documentation and code: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html

Comment: language? platform? particular RNG?

Comment: Is there a feature in assess of NIST?

Comment: That suite is designed to test RNG. Do you have particular RNG to test? What language is used to call this RNG?

Comment: I understand. 
I am able to make it read file with random bits and conduct the tests. However, since it generates bits for testing as well, I like to know how I can pipe it out to a file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, if you have terminal/command prompt open, just redirect output to file

Comment: like this:    rng > output

Comment: Is `rng` an actual command? Could you provide the actual command, as NIST test suite as several RNG?